# Create Apache-Jmeter project file - using java

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to create jmeter(.jmx) file dynamically in java using JMeterAPI and run the file using non-GUI mode. But while trying to generate the ".jmx" file its not generated as expected. It would be helpful that if I could get an working sample.

I had tried the below code:

```
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("jmeter.properties");

HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();     
HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
httpSampler.setDomain("localhost");
httpSampler.setPort(5000);
httpSampler.setPath("/api/v1/data");
httpSampler.setMethod("GET");

TestElement loopCtrl = new LoopController();
((LoopController)loopCtrl).setLoops(1);
((LoopController)loopCtrl).addTestElement(httpSampler);
((LoopController)loopCtrl).setFirst(true);

SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
threadGroup.setSamplerController((LoopController)loopCtrl);

TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST PLAN");
hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
hashTree.add("loopCtrl", loopCtrl);
hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
hashTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);       

try {SaveService.saveTree(hashTree, new FileOutputStream("jmxFile.jmx"));}
catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

But I am not getting the JMX file as expected. Instead I am getting the resultant in the file as below:
[Jmx File Genrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXisj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing few important things:

1. You need to call [JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#setJMeterHome(java.lang.String)) function and provide the path to your JMeter installation
2. You need to set [TestElement.TEST_CLASS](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestElement.html#TEST_CLASS) and [TestElement.GUI_CLASS](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestElement.html#GUI_CLASS) to their respective values

Example working code which produces a .jmx script which can be opened in JMeter GUI without issues (as of [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6)):

```
File jmeterHome = new File("/Users/dtikhanski/Applications/jmeter");

String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");

File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "bin" + slash + "jmeter.properties");

JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());

JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());

HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();

HTTPSamplerProxy examplecomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
examplecomSampler.setDomain("localhost");
examplecomSampler.setPort(5000);
examplecomSampler.setPath("/api/v1/data");
examplecomSampler.setMethod("GET");
examplecomSampler.setName("GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/data");
examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
loopController.setLoops(1);
loopController.setFirst(true);
loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
loopController.initialize();

SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, SetupThreadGroup.class.getName());
threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, SetupThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

hashTree.add(testPlan);
HashTree threadGroupHashTree = hashTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
threadGroupHashTree.add(examplecomSampler);

SaveService.saveTree(hashTree, new FileOutputStream("jmxFile.jmx"));
```

More information:

- [JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-command-line)
- [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/) example project

Comment: I can able to create components and set them in hierarchical order. But I couldn't able to make the components in an order. Say I want to have Group01 and Group02, But I want Group01 in first position of test plan and Group02 in the second position. Is it possible to set the order/position of the jmeter components for this scenario?